# ProgressBar crashing activity(null object reference / or not visible)

Tags: java, android

In the following code of my MainActivity (which downloads a json I need in another activity and shows a loading progress bar), which starts before launching HomeActivity, I get a null object reference error (on the getProgress() method), but HomeActivity then starts anyway if I press back button.

I have searched for this kind of error, but the only solution that seems working is the one that let me starts the HomeActivity after some delay, changing setProgress method like this: (but it seems that the bar doesn't change and I don't think it's a real solution to the problem)

```
public void setProgress(ProgressBar bar, int progress) {
        int oldProgress = bar.getProgress();
        int totalProgress = oldProgress + progress;
        bar.setProgress(totalProgress);

        if (bar.getProgress() == 100) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomePage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }, 4000);
        }
    }

----------------------------------------------------------------------

package ...

import ...


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView textView;
    private OkHttpClient httpClient;
    private String url;
    private Request request;
    private static boolean loaded = false;
    private FileInputStream inputStream;
    private FileOutputStream outputStream;
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "data.txt";
    private AlertDialogConnection noResponse;
    private AlertDialogConnection noInternet;
    private AlertDialogConnection serverError;
    private AlertDialogConnection internalError;

    public MainActivity(){
        this.inputStream = null;
        this.outputStream = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

        this.httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        this.url = "my url";
        this.request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        this.progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        this.progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.progressBarColor), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        this.textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        this.noResponse = new AlertDialogConnection();
        this.noInternet = new AlertDialogConnection();
        this.serverError = new AlertDialogConnection();
        this.internalError = new AlertDialogConnection();

        checkConnectionStatusAndStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }

    public void checkConnectionStatusAndStart(){
        if(checkConnectionStatus())
            requestData();
        else{
            this.noInternet.setTitle("no connection!");
            this.noInternet.setText("connection error!");
            this.noInternet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "no connection!");
        }
    }

    public boolean checkConnectionStatus(){
        boolean wifiConnection = false;
        boolean mobileConnection = false;
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
        if (connectivityManager != null)
            networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if((networkInfo != null) && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                /* Wifi On */
                wifiConnection = true;
            }
            if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
                /* Mobile data On */
                mobileConnection = true;
            }
            return (wifiConnection || mobileConnection);
        }else{
            /* You are not connected */
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void requestData(){
        textView.setText("waiting server...");
        httpClient.connectTimeoutMillis(); //Timeout
        httpClient.writeTimeoutMillis();
        httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                if(!call.isExecuted()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "server error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                Log.d("HTTP-Error", "HTTP error!");
                AlertDialogConnection errorDialog = new AlertDialogConnection();
                errorDialog.setTitle("server error!");
                errorDialog.setText("server error, try later");
                errorDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "messaging error!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    /* HTTP-code: 200 */
                    final String body = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Setting of suggestion variables!");
                            setProgress(progressBar, 10);
                            try {
                                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(body);
                                try {
                                    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("retrieving server infos!");
                                    saveJSON(json, getApplicationContext());
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    Log.d("File Not Found!", "FileNotFoundException!");
                                    internalError.setTitle("error while saving data!");
                                    internalError.setText("server error, try later");
                                    internalError.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "error while saving data!");
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.d("File Not Found!", "IOException!");
                                    internalError.setTitle("error while saving data!");
                                    internalError.setText("server error, try later");
                                    internalError.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "error while saving data!");
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                setProgress(progressBar, 90);
                                MainActivity.loaded = true;

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d("JSON-Error", "parsing JSON error!");
                                internalError.setTitle("server error!");
                                internalError.setText("server error, try later");
                                internalError.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "JSON messaging error!");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    /* Http-code: 500 */
                    Log.d("HTTP-Error", "server error!");
                    serverError.setTitle("server error!");
                    serverError.setText("server error");
                    serverError.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "server error!");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setProgress(ProgressBar bar, int progress){
        int oldProgress = bar.getProgress();
        int totalProgress = oldProgress + progress;
        bar.setProgress(totalProgress);
        if(bar.getProgress() == 100){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomePage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.onDestroy();
        }
    }

    private void saveJSON(JSONObject json, Context context) throws IOException {
        outputStream = null;
        try{
            outputStream = context.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(json.toString().getBytes());
        }finally {
            if(outputStream != null){
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public JSONObject loadJSON(Context context) throws IOException, JSONException {
        inputStream = context.openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(reader.readLine());
        inputStream.close();
        return jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        this.httpClient = null;
        this.noResponse = null;
        this.noInternet = null;
        this.serverError = null;
        this.internalError = null;
        this.request = null;
        this.textView = null;
        this.progressBar = null;
        this.url = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if(!loaded){
            checkConnectionStatusAndStart();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        if(!loaded){
            checkConnectionStatusAndStart();
        }
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(!loaded ){
            checkConnectionStatusAndStart();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

why u adding this when initialization ..

Comment: check your progressbar id in layout file

Comment: @satyan_android deleting 'this' doesn't change...the layout id seems correct.

Comment: Could it be a solution calling onStop() instead of onDestroy() in setProgress method?